# Phar error, can't find stub.php

Tags: php, phar

I created a Phar archive of Zend Framework but I get the following error:
`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar://z3.phar/stub.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')`

This is the stub.php I used:
`<?php
__HALT_COMPILER();`

I created the archive using http://empir.sourceforge.net/
I also tried creating the archive without empir using a tutorial from a blog.

I got the same error, both times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced include () with:
`set_include_path('phar://z3.phar' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());`

and it worked as intended.

I wrongly believed that including a phar with an empty stub would achive the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP interpreter doesn't have the `phar://` stream wrapper enabled (see phpinfo). That's why you get this error.
Moreover you should actually just be using:

```
include("z3.phar");
```

This is supposed to run the [stub file](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.stub.php). Which is of course of little use, if you have a dummy stub file there. It's however possible to have the stub file contain the phar:// implementation from http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Archive - which would allow the .phar to function on PHP interpreters without builtin phar:// stream wrapper support.

I could swear I've read that somewhere. But for simplicity you could just include PHP_Archive manually and enable phar:// support this way.

```
stream_wrapper_register('phar', 'PHP_Archive');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately it seems it is not the case. Phar is a registered stream (i see that in phpinfo)  and is enabled by the extension. In the code, I do use include("z3.phar"). The error message displays is with phar:// for some reason. PHP version is 5.3.5